# Copying existing files into a server SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm facing of difficulties to change a files into CSV and save it into local environment. How can I achieve this? Try to look around but seem like not what I'm looking for.

I'm running on SharePoint 2010. Before this, this code only grab data from SharePoint and turn it into xlsx and update it into our web.

```
    private static void GenerateSPGroupUsersReport() //
    {
        Log("Generate Sharepoint Group Users Report");

        DataSet dsSecurityReport = new DataSet();
        string ConnectedWebURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPGroupUsersWebURL"];
        //string[] strURL = ConnectedWebURL.Split(';');
        DataTable dTblSPGroupUser = new DataTable();
        dTblSPGroupUser.Columns.Add("SiteURL", typeof(string));
        dTblSPGroupUser.Columns.Add("SharepointGroup", typeof(string));
        dTblSPGroupUser.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
        // Hafees add 10/22/2019
        dTblSPGroupUser.Columns.Add("UserLanID", typeof(string));
        dTblSPGroupUser.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));

        SPSite site = new SPSite(ConnectedWebURL);

        SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;

        foreach (SPSite s in webApp.Sites)
        {
            SPGroupCollection groupCol = s.RootWeb.SiteGroups;

            foreach (SPGroup group in groupCol)
            {
                // Hafees include group.Users, user.Email
                foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
                {
                    dTblSPGroupUser.Rows.Add(s.Url, group.Name, user.Name, user.LoginName, user.Email);
                }
                //bool contains = dTblSPGroupUser.AsEnumerable().Any(rowC => group.Name == rowC.Field<string>("SharepointGroup"));

                //if (!contains)
                //{
                //    foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
                //    {
                //        dTblSPGroupUser.Rows.Add(s.Url, group.Name, user.Name);
                //    }
                //}
            }
        }

        DataSet dsSPGroup = new DataSet();
        dsSPGroup.Tables.Add(dTblSPGroupUser);

        SaveIntoSPLibrary(site, dsSPGroup, "GroupUsers_" + ConnectedWebURL.Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "").Replace(":", "-").Trim());

        Log("Generate Sharepoint Group Users Report Complete");
    }
```

// This is where I generate the group of user report.

```
    private static void SaveIntoSPLibrary(SPSite site, DataSet ds, string fileName)
    {
        string UIResourceServerRelativeWebURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UIResourceServerRelativeWebURL"];
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(UIResourceServerRelativeWebURL))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = GenerateExcelFile(ds);

            string CustomReportLibrary = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomReportLibrary"];
            string strFileName = String.Format(fileName + ".{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

            Log("Saving into SP Library. " + CustomReportLibrary + strFileName);

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPFile file = web.Files.Add(CustomReportLibrary + strFileName, byteArray, true);
            file.Item["Year"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            file.Item["Month"] = string.Format("{0}. {1}", DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
            file.Item.Update();
            file.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }

    }
```

// This is where the files save into xlsx and update it into SharePoint Library.

I try to do a copy of SaveIntoLibrary with abit of modification, I change to CSV files and create a new configurationManager which it will point into my local directory. But seem I'm wrong at somewhere. The files still didn't get into my local directory. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should export the DataTable report data to local CSV,

Check the code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244875/generate-csv-file-in-asp-net), this will output the csv file so you could save to your local.

```
var dataTable = GetData();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> rows = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName); 
    }

    builder.Append(string.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray())).Append("\n");

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            object item = row[column];

            currentRow.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        rows.Add(string.Join(",", currentRow.ToArray()));
    }

    builder.Append(string.Join("\n", rows.ToArray()));

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
    Response.Write(builder.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Comment: It is possible if I recreate SaveIntoSPLibrary2 and change it into other name let say. And I configure new path which is my local folder. Then at my report generating, I just add SaveIntoSPLibrary2 (site, dsSPGroup, "GroupUsers_A); will it work this way?

Comment: You should know about the API, web.Files.Add can't save file to your local.