# xls content type change

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

My application generates a .xls file whose content is HTML. When this file is opened in newer versions of office i get the following error.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imZG5.png)

If i open the file and save as .xls by changing the type from web page to .xls the error is removed.

[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rx5C.png)  ---->  [To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg49f.png)

Is there any way to do this using a program in c# or any other technology (Without using any third party library is more preferred)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CSV file which is readable in Excel without libraries (as e.g. shown in [Generate CSV file in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244875/generate-csv-file-in-asp-net)), or a XLS file using a library (as e.g. shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic)).